# Windshield Replacement on 2005 Hyundai Elantra, Key Fob no longer working?

Tags: hyundai, key, windshield, elantra, fob

I had a windshield replaced on a 2005 Hyundai Elantra, and coincidentally the key fob no longer works. I can open the door using the physical key, but the alarm goes off and I am unable to use the key to turn the ignition on.

Any ideas on what went wrong? How can I fix this issue?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It seems likely to me that before replacing the windshield, the shop disconnected the battery as a safety precaution.  As such, the car lost its FOB programming.

According to the information here:

[Key FOB Instructions](https://itstillruns.com/program-hyundai-key-fob-7292112.html)

> Dealer programmed Hyundai keyless entry FOBs must be reprogrammed
> after each vehicle or FOB battery replacement.

The procedure is:

> Step 1 Sit in the driver's seat of your Hyundai vehicle. Close all of
> the vehicle's doors behind you.
>
> Step 2 Stick the key to your Hyundai into the vehicle's ignition
> cylinder. Turn the key to the "ACC" or "Accessory" ignition position.
>
> Hold down the "Open" or "Unlock" button on the keyless entry FOB until
> the vehicle's lights flash. The keyless entry FOB is now reprogrammed
> to your Hyundai vehicle.